# How to display the y_axis name of a xlsxwriter column chart horizontally, at the top of the axis?

Tags: python, excel, charts, xlsxwriter

I am using XlsxWriter to do create column charts with the y axis name showing horizontally at the top of the axis. The default orientation for the y axis name seems to be vertical, reading from bottom to top.

So I'm using the name font rotation to try to position it horizontally, reading from left to right. It all works fine for any rotation angle from -90 to 90, except for 0 (zero), which should be the horizontal orientation. It seems that when rotation is set to 0 (zero) it is simply disregarded and the name is shown vertically.

The workaround that achieves a visuaaly acceptable result is setting rotation to 1, or -1. This works for short names, but for longer names it starts to be noticeable that the text is not at 0 (zero) degrees - horizontal.

I am using Python version Python 3.8.3, xlsxwriter version 1.2.9,  and Excel 365.

Here is some code that demonstrates the problem:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
    [3, 6, 9, 12, 15],
]

worksheet.write_column('A1', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B1', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C1', data[2])

chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5'})

chart.set_title({'name': 'Some Title', 
                 'name_font': {'rotation': 0}})

chart.set_y_axis({'visible': False,
                  'name': 'Y Axis', 
                  'name_font': {'size': 14, 'bold': False, 'italic': True, 'rotation': 0},
                  'name_layout': {'x': 0.025, 'y': 0.075}})

worksheet.insert_chart('E1', chart)

workbook.close()
```

Any ideas on how to show the y axis name horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That unfortunately is due to a small bug. I've fixed it in XlsxWriter [release 1.4.0](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/changes.html).

With the fix in place the output from your (nicely detailed) program is as expected:

[image]

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks!

Comment: The new version works great for my application. Thanks again! For your info @jmcnamara, I did some additional testing and the results seem a bit inconsistent when the y_axis name is set dynamicallly through a formula suchs as `'name': '=A1'` or `'name': '=Sheet1!A1'` (as opposed to a string such as `'name': 'Y Axis'`).

Comment: @frnd.frts, You are correct. Maybe open a bug report on that. I'll work on a fix in the meantime.

Comment: Ok. I've pushed a fix for that to main. Note, you should include the sheet name in the formula, like Excel does: `'name': '=Sheet1!$A$1'`.